# how to use date in where clause while inserting values into table using PLSQL store procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

This is the code i used in stored procedure;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_STORE_PROCEDURE (new_date in date)
IS
BEGIN
execute immediate 'INSERT INTO TEMP_1 (  ID CHAR(10), 
                                         A_CNT NUMBER,
                                         JOIN_DT DATE,
                                      ) 
                                      SELECT 
                                         L1.ID,
                                         L1.A_CNT,
                                         L1.JOIN_DT,
                                      FROM ACTVY_1 L1 
                                      WHERE L1.JOIN_DT = new_date';
END;

===========================================================
```

Below is the code i used to call store procedure with passing value. value is date which store procedure reciece and used to pull date from a table. but it is giving me error.

```
DECLARE
  a_date   DATE;

BEGIN
a_date :=to_DATE ('01-NOV-2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY');
MY_STORE_PROCEDURE(a_date);
END;
```

Please suggest is there any syntax error or what is issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, there is no reason to use dynamic SQL.  You also have a bunch of errors.  Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_STORE_PROCEDURE (new_date IN DATE)
IS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO TEMP_1 (ID, A_CNT, JOIN_DT)
      SELECT L1.ID, L1.A_CNT, L1.JOIN_DT
        FROM ACTVY_1 L1
       WHERE L1.JOIN_DT = new_date;
END;
```

Comment: Great thanks for reply. Now i have another issue. Table ACTVY_1 has different owner than me. so, its saying "table/view doesnt exist" if i use this query without procedure its working fine but inside procedure it give that error. any help.

Comment: Then open a new question.  This one was answered completely.